# htacess for root folder with wordpress install and subdirectory for another domain

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have a wordpress install in my website directory e.g.( public_html/wp-content, public_html/wp-admin, public_html/wp-includes) and I have a subdirectory to which points to another domain public_html/anotherdomain.com

I don't want the another domain messing up the root wordpress install.
ex. anotherdomain.com should only go to public_html/anotherdomain.com and originialdomain.com should access public_html folder excluding the anotherdomain.com.

My question is what is the best approach for this?

1. using htaccess?
2. using the cpanel addon domain and make a subdirectory for the wordpress install?

Answer (score 0):

If you use .htaccess you can block access to anotherdomain.com from your wordpress site. This will work but is kind of a sloppy hack and doesn't plan for the future pretty well. Are you going to keep doing this when you get more domains and install them.

The cleaner way to do it is what I think you are saying in your number 2. Give the wordpress site it's own directory that is a peer with anotherdomain.com. This way it will work the same if you have 1, 2, or 10 domains.